# How do I pass two 'echo n' responses to the same command in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-line-arguments

I need to run the following batch file and pass "N" twice. I can figure out how to pass it once, but twice I just can't figure out:

```
@ECHO OFF

Regedt32 /s registrychanges.reg
echo n | gpupdate /force /sync
shutdown /r /f /t 0
```

The gpupdate /force /sync requires "N" twice. Even if I do `echo n | echo n | gpupdate /force /sync` it just hangs at the prompt for the second n.

Is there actually a way to pass two echo responses in a batch file for the same command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a code block and pipe to the command.

```
(
echo n
echo n
)|gpupdate /force /sync
```

Comment: If necessary, you should be able to do it in a single line too, ```(echo n& echo n) | ...```.

Comment: @squashman - That worked exactly as needed. Thank you!